# Dalgona Toffee Burns When Adding Baking Soda

Tags: candy, toffee, melting-sugar

I've tried this every way from Sunday. I've had some success using a bit of corn syrup but I don't get the rise and melt in your mouth Texture that I prefer.

So basically it's 4tbsp of white sugar,1tbsp wate, 1tsp of baking soda.

It seems to me that no matter how lightly I caramelise my sugar I end up with a very dark toffee brittle as the baking soda seems to darken it. I even end up with a lighter ring around the outside and the inside is a much darker crumb.

The texture is perfect, melt in your crumble that can be crumbled over a glass of milk and it's delicious, but it's an acquired taste and I'm struggling to get it to the perfect level of caramelised.

Any suggestions or anyone have experience with this style of puffed candy using baking soda?